# A problem on right-click menu using Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net

I want to add a right click menu to a dynamic added button by using ContextMenuStr. My code are as follows:

```
 Public Class Form1
    Private mybutton As New Button
    Private i As Integer
    Private mybutton_cms As ContextMenuStrip = New ContextMenuStrip()


    Private Sub TreeView1_AfterSelect(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.AfterSelect

    If e.Node.Text = "addbutton" Then                          
    ***Dim mybutton As New Button***
        Me.Controls.Add(mybutton)
        i = i + 1          'give a ID to the dynamic added button
        mybutton.Left = 200                       
        mybutton.Top = 200                         
        mybutton.Name = "mybutton"
        AddHandler mybutton.MouseMove, AddressOf mybutton_MouseMove     
    ElseIf e.Node.Text = "deletebutton" Then                            
        Me.Controls.RemoveByKey("mybutton")
        i = i - 1      'delete the the ID of button
    End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

       Dim tsm As ToolStripMenuItem = New ToolStripMenuItem("change icon")
       mybutton_cms.Items.Add(tsm)

       mybutton.ContextMenuStrip = mybutton_cms
    End Sub


    Private Sub mybutton_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)

       OBJ_Resize.ResizeOBJ(sender, e, Me)                                
       Dim file As New IO.StreamWriter("data2.xml", OpenMode.Append)       
       file.WriteLine("width=" & sender.width)
       file.WriteLine("height=" & sender.height)
       file.WriteLine("x=" & sender.left)
       file.WriteLine("y=" & sender.top)
       file.Close()

    End Sub


   Private Sub mybutton_changeicon(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)

      changeIcon.changeicon(sender, e)

     End Sub
   End Classa
```

there is a bug that if I delete the Code referenced with *,namely :

```
     Dim mybutton As New Button
```

when I run the code, there is no right click menu on the button dynamiclly added.
And if I add this code,there is only one dynamical added button on the form1. But the rigtht click menu will show.
What I want to do is click “addbutton” once to get a button, and each button can have a right-click menu
What's wrong with my code?

Beside,could you plese tell me How to add left-click events to the right menu item？
Thanks!

Comment: `Private mybutton As New Button` will ever only be the one and same button, unless you set `mybutton = New Button` somewhere in your code. `Dim mybutton As New Button` creates a **new** button **every time** you press `addbutton`. The variable _has the same name_ as your class level variable, but it's **not** the same variable.

Comment: If you want all buttons to have the same context menu, remove the class level `Private mybutton As New Button` variable and set each `mybutton`'s context menu when you've pressed `addbutton` instead of at form load.

Comment: I replaced    Dim mybutton as new button    with    mybutton=new button    ,but the right click menu still didn't show. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: and now the bug is if I added my button=new button, the  right click menu wii not show. If I delete the my button=new button,the menu will appear but there is only one dynamical added button on the form1 no matter how many times I click  the "addbutton".

Comment: and now the bug is if I added my button=new button, the  right click menu wii not show. If I delete the my button=new button,the menu will appear but there is only one dynamical added button on the form1 no matter how many times I click  the "addbutton".

Comment: Please re-read my comments carefully. I told you to _**remove**_ `Private mybutton As New Button` altogether and _**keep**_ `Dim mybutton As New Button`, then add the context menu _**when you click**_ `addbutton`, _**not**_ at form load.

Comment: In general you shouldn't keep class level variables of single controls unless they're designer-generated or serve as singletons that can be used in many instances (like your context menu). Always declare the rest _only when you are to add them to your form_ and give them a unique [name](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.name) if you want to [reference them later](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.item?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_Control_ControlCollection_Item_System_String_).

Comment: Thank you! I have sovled the problem.I delete the code `Private mybutton As New Button ` , change the code`mybutto.ContextMenuStrip = mybutton_cms` to `sender.ContextMenuStrip = mybutton_cms` .  but when I run it , there is a new problem that: Unable to cast object of type 'System.EventArgs`'to type System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs? what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Don't use `sender`! Simply move `mybutton.ContextMenuStrip = mybutton_cms` inside `If e.Node.Text = "addbutton" Then` and you're good to go. As for the error: I don't know as I don't know on which line it occurs.